# React - pass classNames to component as props. similar to in vue js

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I wanted to achieve the same feature in react which is available in vue js.

`<CustomComp :class="new" />`

how do I do it without adding like

`<CustomComp customName="new" />`

```
const CustomComp = ({customName}) => {
   return <div className={customName} />
```

Comment: Code here looks correct. What's the problem exactly? You can use `customName={someVariable}` to get similar functionality as Vue (I think--I'm not super familiar with Vue, but I understand `:` lets you evaluate the string as state or "data" in Vue parlance(?)).

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're asking. What problem are you trying to solve? what would it looks like in your ideal world?

Answer (score 2):

For Vue.js, this attributes of a component will be inherited by the root of the component. (related [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance))

But for React.js, there is no such default behavior, you should do it manually like what you have done.